# GeoServer rendering arc in low quality

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I am using OpenLayers 3 and GeoServer WMS to render a list of sites that have arcs. The arc of each site its rendering very bad, appearing like two lines. When I increase the zoom it looks a bit better, but does not looks soft.

[image]

[image]

How I can increase the quality of the rendering on GeoServer?

OpenLayers code:

```
 wms_celdas_3g.setSource(new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: serverurl,
      params: {layers:'{{wms_layer_double}}',transparent: 'true',format: "image/png8", CQL_FILTER:"network = '3G'"},
      serverType: 'geoserver'
    }));
```

Style of GeoServer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>celdas_all</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Name>celdas_all</Name>
            <Title>geoserver style</Title>
            <Abstract>Generated by GeoServer</Abstract>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Filter>
                        <And>
                            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                <PropertyName>network</PropertyName>
                                <Literal>2G</Literal>
                            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        </And>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#41F0F0</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.3</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#41F0F0</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Filter>
                        <And>
                            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                <PropertyName>network</PropertyName>
                                <Literal>3G</Literal>
                            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        </And>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#3f51b5</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.3</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#3f51b5</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Filter>
                        <And>
                            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                <PropertyName>network</PropertyName>
                                <Literal>LTE</Literal>
                            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        </And>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#008300</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#008300</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.3</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Can you say what the data is, what the styling is, and how you are calling the WMS layer (i.e. at least the relevant part of the OL3 code)?

Comment: can you add an example arc as WKT, GeoServer just draws what is present in the data so it is probably an issue there. What sort of DataStore are you using

Comment: Indeed, is the arc an actual circular arc segment in the data, or is it just approximated by a set of straight lines?

Comment: yes you are right. and excume the delayed of my response.